# Require.js text plugin is appending .js to my html template

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs

I'm trying to load a template like this:

```
define [
    'jquery'
    'underscore'
    'backbone'
    'mustache'
    'text!templates/linksnip.html'
], ($, _, Backbone, Mustache, templateView) ->

    // do stuff
```

It works fine locally and loads it from `/assets/scripts/js/templates/linksnip.html`. For whatever reason when I push it to my testing environment which uses a separate domain for my cdn it tries to load it like this `http://testing.mycdn.com/scripts/js/templates/linksnip.html.js`. Any idea why it is it trying to append the `.js` extension?

Comment: Do you include `text` plugin? http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to same origin security restrictions. You can use the r.js optimizer with the "optimizeAllPluginResources" option set to true to generate js files of the templates.